# Automatically have Terms & Conditions checked on checkout page

Tags: checkout

By default when the Terms and Conditions are enabled, visitors are required to tick / check "I agree" (Checkbox Text) to the Terms and Conditions of the website at the end of the checkout process.

To expedite the checkout process, I'd like to have this checkbox already selected.

What is the best method to automatically have the checkbox selected agreeing to the Terms and Conditions of the website on Checkout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just edit `template/checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml` and add `checked="checked"` on the checkbox input.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="agreement-<?php echo $_a->getId()?>" name="agreement[<?php echo $_a->getId()?>]" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_a->getCheckboxText()) ?>" class="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```

Comment: Beautiful! Wish I could give more credit for speed. Thanks Marius!!